# List customer ID, name and all of his/her accounts

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
customers:
+------------+--------------+ 
| cid        | Name         | 
+------------+--------------+ 
| 1          | Bob          |
| 2          | John         | 
| 3          | Jane         | 
+------------+--------------+ 
accounts:
+------------+--------------+ 
| aid        | type         | 
+------------+--------------+ 
| 1          | Checking     |
| 2          | Saving       | 
| 3          | CD           | 
+------------+--------------+ 
transactions:
+------------+--------------+--------------+ 
| tid        | cid          | aid          | 
+------------+--------------+--------------+ 
| 1          | 1            | 1            | 
| 2          | 2            | 1            | 
| 3          | 1            | 2            | 
| 4          | 2            | 3            | 
| 5          | 3            | 1            | 
+------------+--------------+--------------+
```

I am trying to write a plsql procedure that, given the customer id as a parameter, will display his/her id, name and all accounts. Displaying the id and name is simple enough. What I'm not sure about is how to get all the accounts that are linked to the customer id and how to retrieve more than a single account.

Comment: the issue is, in this schema your accounts aren't linked to your customers directly - only through transactions - so all you can do in this schema is to get all accounts that have been part of specified client's transactions.

Answer (score 0):

An ideea can be:

```
select c.cid, c.name, a.type
from customers c
left join transactions t on (t.cid = c.cid)
left join accounts a on (a.aid = t.aid)
where c.cid = :customer_id
group by c.cid, c.name, a.type;
```

the group by is needed because can be more transactions.

Further, if you want to see one line:

```
select cid, name, LISTAGG(type, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY type) as account_types
from(
    select distinct c.cid, c.name, a.type
    from customers c
    left join transactions t on (t.cid = c.cid)
    left join accounts a on (a.aid = t.aid)
    where c.cid = :customer_id

)
group by cid, name;
```

Putting this into a stored procedure/function is too simple, so I let it to you.